# How can I save an string pk into int pk?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a problem with a submit form when I want to save the profile ID the form have an error, i dont understand why because in the console all is ok but the form_valis is false, so think because the ModelChoiseField send a pk in sting format so how can i convert the string pk to int pk ?

My Form

class UsuarioForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
id_perfil = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Perfil.objects.filter(status='1'), label="Perfil" ,empty_label="Seleciona perfil", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

My Models

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    id_usuario = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id_perfil = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Perfil(models.Model):
    id_perfil = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The save method

```
def save_usuario_form(request, form, template_name):
data = dict()
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        usuario = form.save(commit=False)
        if usuario.status == '':
            usuario.status = '1'
            usuario.id_usuario_alt = '1'
        elif usuario.status == '1':
            usuario.status = '2'
        form.save()
        data['form_is_valid']= True
        usuarios = Usuario.objects.filter(status='1').order_by('id_usuario')[:5]
        data['html_usuario_list'] = render_to_string('back/Modulo_usuarios/usuarios_list.html',{
            'usuarios':usuarios
        })
    else:
        data['form_is_valid']= False
context = {'form':form}
data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYMUd.png)

[All fields are fill  and post method is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ltx.png)

Comment: can you please show us your save and clean method ?

Comment: chek my def save method

Comment: you have 2 required fields that you did not fill  **nombre** and **status**

Comment: i added the complete save method, the field nombre is fill when the form_valid =True, asi you can see in the images the all fields are fill but always the method detect form_valid = False

Comment: Use a foreign key  for **id_perfil** in the **Usuario** model, `id_perfil = models.ForeignKey("Perfil")`

Comment: I think in that but in the tables don't exist a relationship with Usuario and Perfiles, so i just want to save the value of the option selected, in the field Id_perfil.

Comment: before saving the form use `form.id_perfil = int(form.id_perfil)`

Comment: I try but nothing, the inspector shows  Form_is_valid=False